# weird artifacts with procedural texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

In blender cycles I tryed to create a brushed aluminum texture using a node setup with a voronoi texture and a mapping node but when it was rendered I noticed there was a weird ripple artifact when using this node setup [image]

here is a more zoomed in look at the artifact 
[image]

here is the node setup
[image]

here is the blend
[image]

Comment: Please add the .blend

Comment: The weird ripple seems to be apparent in both though?

Comment: yeah the second image was just to show it zoomed in more to make the artifact more visible